# Customised Hotword to trigger google assistant

Tags: python

I've been surfing for the past two days but in vain. I wanted to trigger my google assistant using customised Hotword. I did train my voice and downloaded the .pmdl file and the decoder aswell from snowboy kitty. what do I do next?

Traceback (most recent call last): File "demo.py", line 1, in import snowboydecoder File "/home/pi/Downloads/rpi-arm-raspbian-8.0-1.1.1/snowboydecoder.py", line 5, in import snowboydetect File "/home/pi/Downloads/rpi-arm-raspbian-8.0-1.1.1/snowboydetect.py", line 28, in _snowboydetect = swig_import_helper() File "/home/pi/Downloads/rpi-arm-raspbian-8.0-1.1.1/snowboydetect.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper _mod = imp.load_module('_snowboydetect', fp, pathname, description) File "/home/pi/venv/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module return load_dynamic(name, filename, file) File "/home/pi/venv/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic return _load(spec) ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__snowboydetect)

Answer (score 0):

I use snowboy and it works pretty well. Once you have trained the model you can download these examples: demo1, demo2, etc. There are different variants.
https://github.com/Kitt-AI/snowboy/tree/master/examples/Python
I would recommend the following steps:
 - Generate an audio file containing the keyword an 2nd audio file not containing it. Use a synthesizer or your real voice
 - Run python example where it gets the audio input from microphone: https://github.com/Kitt-AI/snowboy/blob/master/examples/Python/demo.py
 - Play the audio files generated in the first step and observe snowboy script output
Hope it helps, Ester

Comment: I'm already done with the steps you've mentioned.How do I link it with the assistant? @EsterGonzalezDeLangarica

Comment: Take a look at https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/extend/custom-actions to make your own assistant / bot. Your main program may do the hotword detection and then you can trigger the logic defined in the Google skills.

Comment: I tried to follow up but I'm facing a problem while importing snowboy .

Comment: Can you be more specific? Copy paste the problem you get?